# Hostname (.local) not resolve on SmartPhone but only on PCs connected by cable

Tags: networking, dns, hostname

in my house I own 3 PCs and 2 smartphones

- PC-1 "connected via wifi" = Notebook with Ubuntu Server (my server
  personal), hostname "servernote.local" / ip 192.168.0.104

  PC-2 "cabled" = Windows PC (normally solves
  servernote.local)

  PC-3 "cabled" = Windows PC (normally solves
  servernote.local)
- Smartphone 1 (Wifi obviously...) = ping and access via IP, but not
  resolve hostname servernote.local

  Smartphone 2 (Wifi obviously...) = ping and access via IP, but not
  resolve hostname servernote.local

basically, by PCs connected via cable, I can access my server through "http://servernote.local".
But I can't on smartphones, only by IP

i'm new to linux, and i'm playing around with a server a bit to learn a few things.

If anyone has any idea what might be going on, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I just tried this with an Android 12 phone (Pixel 3). <hostname>.local works with the phone on WiFi and the <hostname> on cable. I can't reproduce your problem. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1433453/edit) and add which phone and the version of the OS on the phone.

Comment: Android 10 and Iphone, whatever model the hostname is is not resolved on phones or any device on the same network but on wifi. Devices connected by cables work perfectly as they should.

Comment: I can use <hostname>.local from my laptop on WiFi and from my phone on WiFi. You probably need phones with more recent OS. This is not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: forgot to mention that it's an iPhone 13, from the tests I did, any device on the wifi network is not resolving the <hostname> of the ubuntu server, the error appears in the browser "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" and ping <hostname> does not work, but if pinging the IP it works.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all these information.